# Refactor my Javascript IF statement

Tags: javascript, refactoring, conditional-statements

I have been given some very ugly code I need to refactor & I am unsure on the best way to tackle it. To me, it works as I should & everytime I try to change it, it seems to introduce a bug.

Any ideas would be great.

```
  if (product) {
    if (product.available) {
      $addToCart.removeClass('disabled').prop('disabled', false);

      if (lang_key_change) {
        $addToCartText.html(lang_key_change);
      } else {
        $addToCartText.html({{ 'add_to_cart'}});
      }

    } else {
      $addToCart.addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
      $addToCartText.html({{ 'sold_out'}});
    }

  } else {
    $addToCart.addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
    $addToCartText.html({{ 'unavailable'}});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below refactored code

```
    $addToCart.addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
if (product && product.available) {   
    $addToCart.removeClass('disabled').prop('disabled', false);
    $addToCartText.html(lang_key_change? lang_key_change: {{ 'add_to_cart'}});
}
else if (product && product.available === false) {     
    $addToCartText.html({{ 'sold_out'}});
}
else {   
    $addToCartText.html({{ 'unavailable'}});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need any `if` statement, check here

```
 $addToCart.toggleClass('disabled', !product || ( product && !product.available ) );
 $addToCart.prop('disabled', !product || ( product && !product.available ) );
 $addToCartText.html( !product ? {{ 'unavailable'}} : ( !product.available ? {{ 'sold_out'}} : ( lang_key_change || {{ 'add_to_cart'}} ) )  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect. What a clean up